# Android. AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Can I do periodically tack with `AlarmManager` for example two days in week(any) and every fixed hours in day?
How something:

```
every Sunday: every two hours
every Friday: every four hours
eth..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set one alarm and when it fires set the new alarm. I think that's the only way to make non-constant intervals between alarms. `setRepeating()` and `setInexactRepeating()` methods of AlarmManager are designed only for constant intervals.

Comment: Thank you. It was my first idea, but I hoped what exist standard methods to do this